# Popup Div anchor at mouse hover/click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web-applications

I am new in Web Programming.

I want to implement something like in facebook, when we hover our mouse on the link, a arrow-floating-div that anchor on the link will be showed on top of it.

How do you all address that kind of component? The closest library that I found is http://gristmill.github.com/jquery-popbox/ This does not work sometime, in some browser. Further search for "Popbox" does not show any useful result. Can anyone recommend any similar library like the link I posted? It can be using Jquery, Javascript, CSS, html or etc.

Instead of using library, can anyone show me how to do it without using library, in a simplest of way. I just want to know the rough idea behind. Most of the library come with complicated code, is hard to learn for beginner.

Thank very much in advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fedmich/Aapw6/

You'll need to create an image of the arrow on top and centered in the popup box and then generally move the popup box to follow the target anchor.

```
$('.hover').hover(function(){
        var popup_div = $('.popup_div');
        var obj = $(this);
        var offset = obj.offset();

        var new_top = offset.top + 30;

        var new_left = offset.left;

        new_left = new_left - ( popup_div.width() / 2);
        new_left = new_left + ( obj.width() / 2);

        popup_div.css('left', new_left + 'px');
        popup_div.css('top', new_top + 'px');

        popup_div.show();
    }
    , function (){
        //hovered away so hide popup
        $('.popup_div').hide();
    }
    );
```

CSS code should be position absolute

```
.popup_div{
    position:absolute;
    left:100px;
    top:100px;
    border:1px solid red;
    background-color:blue;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    background:url("http://i.imgur.com/zFWft.png") no-repeat scroll center 0 transparent;
    text-align:left;
}
```

---

you could do this via getting the positioning of the target div and then getting the center by dividing the width by half and adding it to the left.

```
    new_left =  hovered_thing.left + (hovered_thing.width / 2) - (popup_div.width / 2)
```

let me make you some fiddle for this shortly
on another note though, have you tried hovercards? might be similar to what you want to do

http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/Hovercard

Comment: Thank for your demo. It is simple enough to understand.

Answer (score 1):

jquery ui provides a [dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) feature

the idea behind it that you have your anchor bind that it displays and hides you popup

```
$('#anchor').bind({
    'mouseenter' : function() {
        $('#popUp').show();
    },
    'mouseleave' : function() {
        $('#popUp').hide();
    }
});
```

you will have to set the position of the popup to.
note that only if the popup divs display is not none you can use **$('#popup').outerWidth()/2** and **$('#anchor').outerWidth() /2** ...